# Вставить функцию при нажатии кнопки(telebot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, telebot

Как вызывать функцию при нажатии кнопки в telebot?

После того как нажимается "figure" необходимо, чтобы бот вызывал функцию kr()
kr() состоит из ввода переменных, вычисления по формуле с этими переменными и выводом результата.

```
# Обработчик нажатий на кнопки
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    # Если нажали на одну из  кнопок — просим ввести переменные
    if call.data == "figure":
        @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
        def kr(message):
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Найдем площадь круга:")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# Обработчик нажатий на кнопки
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    # Если нажали на одну из  кнопок — просим ввести переменные
    if call.data == "figure":
       a = kr(call.message) # если kr() возвращает площадь круга
       bot.send_message(call.message.from_user.id, "Найдем площадь круга:{}".format(a))
       # bot.send_message(call.message.from_user.id, "Найдем площадь круга:{}".format(kr(call.message)))
```

- не требуется указывать ещё один `handler`
- для вызова функции используйте её имя и аргумент `some(args)`
- если функция что-то возвращает, `return`, либо определяйте в переменную, либо сразу вызывайте функцию.